# Localization not working in activity

Tags: android, localization

I have an issue where i have resources for english and spanish. And i had set The locale as follow:

```
 private Settings settings;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settings = new Settings(LoadingScreenActivity.this);
        if(settings.isSpanish()){
            String languageToLoad  = "es"; // your language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
```

Also i have set this in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

settings.isSpanish returns as true. Still the layout shows english text and not spanish.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by doing this in onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    settings = new Settings(WheelActivity.this);
    Log.e("isSpanish", String.valueOf(settings.isSpanish()));
    if(settings.isSpanish()){
        String languageToLoad  = "es"; // your language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

I think its not about the onResume but this part

```
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Though i have to do this in all activity. I am not sure though if this is the right way to go about this. Will wait for a better solution.